# Cloud function for express firebase pagination

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, google-cloud-functions

I am working on **react** project and have used firestore for my database, i am just stuck with firebase pagination , how to use it's method like startAt(), and how to go forward and backword and how to make api calls in sequence,

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example in the firebase documentation:

```
var first = db.collection("cities")
     .orderBy("population")
     .limit(25);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

You can save your lastVisible element in in a state variable and update it, if nextPage button fires.

For this usecase you don´t need cloud functions.

For more information refer to the official firebase documentation: [FirebaseDocs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#web_3)

Comment: Great answer @lukbuz!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lukbuz  Sorry but I am new to cloud functions, and have gone through their documentation, but still stuck with pagination, as your code shows first.get() will fetch first 25 results, but when user will click on next button , same function will run, and it will fetch first 25 results again, and then it will go to next query, can you just create a cloud function or explain in details as documentation is going over my head,  thanks in advance